# browse folders and files inside asset folder

Tags: java, android, file, browser

I have some folders and files and I would like to create a simple file browser that will allow me to browse the folders inside my asset folder then open the files inside those how can I get around it ?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Your question is too broad - add more details to it. Take a look at this for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938942/file-explorer-java

Comment: Note that assets are not files on the device. They are files on your development machine.

Comment: Well, they are actually files in your app's private space. In facts, you can still get them on a device (i.e.: fonts, audio files, whatever file you wouldn't put as a standard resource - in other words, an alternative to using raw).

Comment: Well the idea is,  I have some files organized in some folders my objective is to find a way to browse to these folders and open the files inside them

Comment: You can do it like you would implement a normal file browser. List the directories. List the files. Put all in a listview.

Comment: thank you Greenapps

Answer (score 0):

Access the Assets folder files do as follows:

1- List all the files in the assets folder:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
String[] files = assetManager.list("");
```

2- Open a certain file:

```
InputStream input = assetManager.open(assetName);
```

Further reading:

- [Trying to access sub folders in assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652009/trying-to-access-sub-folders-in-assets-folder)
- [how to reference an asset in a library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346889/how-to-reference-an-asset-in-a-library-project)